# Raspberry Pi wont turn on with OpenELEC

Tags: boot, hdmi, openelec

I just got a raspberry pi board, connected with HDMI to LG TV

Loaded OpenELEC-RPi.arm-2.95.3 on a 32 Gig SD Card and it didn't turn on any LED (except PWR and ACT).

Later I loaded latest Raspbian “wheezy”, that booted with all LED on, but no video, so looking at the [faq](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#No_HDMI_output_at_all), I enabling hdmi_safe=1 option worked.

Reloaded OpenELEC on to SD card, still no boot!!

What can the problem be?

Comment: Try to use a smaller SD card like 4GB- Maybe openelec has issues reading massive SD's - It should just boot. at least see the console.

Comment: I'll try that, but I was able to get Raspbmc working :)

Comment: Same issue here.
I am able to run Raspbmc on a 32GB card but not OpenELEC.
I have tried a few version of the OpenELEC and also tried to install from a PC, Linux and Mac and non of them worked.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What is the SDCard class you're you using ?
it's advised to use Class 6 as minimum.

SDHC Class 2 --> 2 MB/sec
SDHC Class 4 --> 4 MB/sec
SDHC Class 6 --> 6 MB/sec
SDHC Class 10 --> 10 MB/sec

Next Question,

Did you used the Create_SD script in the tar.bz2 of openelec, to create your bootable SD card ?
During this proces did you get any errors ? did all partionion processes passed ?

regards